# Visual Studio not showing WSL2 launch profile

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, c#-9.0

I have just updated my Visual Studio community 2019 to version 16.9.1. But I am not able to see the WSL2 profile as mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2019#start-debugging-with-wsl-2) document.

Also, my machine has all the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2019#prerequisites).

I have tried with the existing and new console app, web app with target framework .net core 3.1 and .NET 5, but not showing the option.

Also, I have tried adding the below settings to the launchSettings.json file, but when running with this change, it shows the error

> The Project does not know how to run the Profile WSL 2.

```
"WSL 2": {
    "commandName": "WSL2",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "https://localhost:5001",
    "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "distributionName": ""
}
```

Comment: please check if you install this component  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3vrm.png. Because we need to install it manually.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I tried with your suggestion, it's working as expected. you can add this as the answer. Also when I run the console app using the WSL2 profile, I am able to debug. But I cannot see the console in my windows system, so it means it is running on WSL. How can I see the app console output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

please check if you install the following component . Because we need to install it manually.

[image]

Comment: I have it installed and it doesn't show up