# Visual Studio 2022 not list WSL as an option in Target System

Tags: visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-2022, wsl-2

I used [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-build-debug-wsl2?view=msvc-170#cross-platform-cmake-development-with-a-wsl-2-distro) to configure VS 2022 (version 17.1.3) for c++ with CMake on WSL.

On point 5 they wrote:

> Select Tools > Options > CMake > General. Select Prefer using CMake Presets for configure, build, and test

This option is not really exist. Instead I used the following, which seems the same:
[image]

Continue to point 7, they wrote that WSL should be list as an option to `Target System` but it is not exist. I only have the option of `Local Machine`.

[image]

Of course I install WSL on my machine and restart it before I tried use it with VS 2022.

What should I do to make VS 2022 list the WSL as an option to Target System?

Comment: I get the same problem. Please let me know if you find a solution. Interestingly I also didn't have that CMake config option.

Comment: I didn't. If you upvote the question maybe it will get more views and someone will help us

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 or 11 and if 11, did you bypass TPM 2?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

Try install “Linux development with C++ ” workload
https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/linux/download-install-and-setup-the-linux-development-workload

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring remote connection to your WSL distro manually https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyAzNYNfme8.

It was also suggested to try to install additional package: [Visual Studio not showing WSL2 launch profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66599090/visual-studio-not-showing-wsl2-launch-profile), however neither of the suggestions helped my case.

**EDIT**: installing 'Linux and embedded development with C++' component solved the issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried your edit. It added "manage connections" to the dropdown but when i click on it i get "Could not load file or assembly......"

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, was fixed for me when I swapped to "Always use CMakePresets.json" and closed + reopened the folder.